# How to kill a thread in a service?

Tags: android

I have a service that runs whenever the screen gets turned on. When I put the phone to sleep, the service and the thread should stop.

I managed to stop the service, but the thread still runs. How can i kill the thread?

```
void runAppCheck(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            getForegroundApplication();
                            compareResults();
                            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                            boolean screenIsOn = pm.isScreenOn();
                            if (!screenIsOn) {
                                Log.i(TAG ,"Screen is OFF, stopping service");
                                stopSelf();
                                //TODO stop thread
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: How to stop a Java thread properly has been discussed so many times, especially on StackOverflow. Why didn't any of the solutions you found when you searched suffice?

Comment: So, this code looks every 10 seconds if the phone-screen is off?

Comment: The solutions i found don't work, one was deprecated and .interrupt() gave me errors.
No the code checks what app is running in the foreground every 10sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your problem entirely, because the answer seem to be quite easy, unless I'm missing something.

Stopping your thread in your example seems to be as easy as calling `return;`, which will end the `public void run()` method and that will end the thread.

```
      ....
                       if (!screenIsOn) {
                            Log.i(TAG ,"Screen is OFF, stopping service");
                            stopSelf();
                            return;
                        }
      ....
```

Update after OP's comment:

If you are not using an `AlarmManager` and you can be sure that your thread still receives some CPU cycles, why do you do a `mHandler.post(....)` call? Why not just skip that `post` call.

```
void runAppCheck(){
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        getForegroundApplication();
                        compareResults();
                        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                        boolean screenIsOn = pm.isScreenOn();
                        if (!screenIsOn) {
                            Log.i(TAG ,"Screen is OFF, stopping service");
                            stopSelf();

                            //stop thread
                            return;
                        }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: BTW: Doing this in a Thread is a bad design, because when your screen is off, your thread will likely not get any CPU time and if it doesn't run, it can't detect whether the screen is off or on... Use an AlarmManager instead to handle these situations: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Unfortunatelly doesn't work, thread still running.
The thread is running even if the screen is off, and even if it didn't it would be ok since i want it to stop when the screen goes off

Comment: I missed the fact that you post yet another Runnable to the ui-thread, so calling return; won't work. Still, use an AlarmManager instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop a `Thread` by using a shared variable that acts as a flag to ask the `Thread` to stop. For example, in your outer `Thread`, declare `private volatile boolean mRunning = true` and change tn the outer `while(true)` to `while(mRunning)`. Then implement a method to request it to cease running:

```
public void terminate() {
    mRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: I can't assign a shared variable to my thread, i tried Thread mRunning = new Thread(new Runnable() {.. but it gives me an error

Comment: can you tell me how please?